# Android: Create Activity not Full Screen with Transparent Background

Tags: android, android-activity, background, transparent

I'd like to create an Activity smaller than full screen and having around it a transparent background.

[image]

Using re-size function I was able to create layer smaller than full screen, but I don't know how to create transparent background.

In my mind, if you tap on the background nothing should happen, but, in my case (simply re-sizing) activity, when you tap somewhere outside of activity, it loses the focus and disappears.

Any ideas?
Many thanks!

Comment: You could achieve this with a Dialog rather than an Activity.

Comment: I've already tried it but it was really difficult because activity is pretty dynamic, inside something is changing by user. Dialog is not "flexible" as activity. But really thanks for your idea!

Comment: Have you tried making a dialog with a custom view? I guess it's hard to know what you are ultimately trying to do.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What about making your own style and putting:

```
<item name="android:windowCloseOnTouchOutside">false</item>
```

Comment: Yeah! It works like a charm, exactly as I want. Another small question, is it possible to set the level of transparency of space outside Activity? Thanks again